# Improve the performance of select first then insert to avoid duplicate record (in mysql & php)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, insert

To avoid duplicate insert I know I can use “INSERT IGNORE” or “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE” in mysql.

But I am using laravel and I know [firstOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods) does not do that. It first makes a SELECT to see if the entry is there and INSERT only when SELECT returns no records. I guess it is becauase `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is specific to MySQL.

It is really bad from performance point of view that I select first then insert ? How much performance impact will that cause compare to “INSERT IGNORE” or “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE” ?

Does it worth the trouble to not use firstOrCreate and write my own php code to “INSERT IGNORE” or “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE” ?

Comment: Question: What do you want to happen should an inset fail due to a duplicate issue?  Do you really want to update, or would just failing be sufficient?

Comment: If the select is using only primary key and you have reasonable amount of rows, I'd say the performance impact in general usage is negligible. You can run into troubles for dumps though, but in such cases you usually don't mind extra time to complete the task.

Comment: You can use Laravel DB Statement to write your own query. firstOrCreate will not create that much issue if indexing is being proper.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just need insert ignore. But I am interested the performance impact of select first then insert.

Comment: @mikiqex Do you have actual data to backup your statement that "the performance impact in general usage is negligible." ?

Comment: @Qiulang Not really, speaking from personal experience. I suspect we're talking about simplest SELECT, like ```SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id = X``` with "id" as INT and PRIMARY KEY, which is by design the fastest data query possible. Actual data depends on how many columns are you ultimately going to query, how many rows are there, how efficient your indexes are, HW specs of your DB server etc. The best way is to try the query yourself on real or assumed data set, using EXPLAIN and profiling in MySQL itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only want `INSERT INTO ... IGNORE` functionality, I would suggest just creating a unique index on the table in question.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD CONSTRAINT cnstr UNIQUE KEY (col1, col2, ...);
```

With this in place, any attempt to insert a record which is duplicate would result in an application error on the PHP side, which you could easily catch and handle.

The problem with doing an insert first to check if a duplicate exists before attempting an insert is that such logic would only work if you ensure that no other DML activity occurs in the table from the time you select to the time the insert completes.  Otherwise, something like the following would be possible:

```
process1: SELECT to check if record exists (assume it does not)
process2: INSERT record (which process1 wants to insert)
process1: INSERT same record (now a duplicate exists)
```

In other words, your PHP application would "think" that no duplicate exists, and insert the record.  But, in the time in between its select and insert, another process happened to insert the same record.

To avoid this, I believe you would need something like a serializable transaction.  But, using a unique constraint is much cleaner, and leaves this responsibility primarily up to the database to handle.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering my question. So what about the the performance impact of select first then insert. Is it really negligible like other comment I got ?

Comment: That's not really the big issue.  The bigger issue is that the approach has a serious flaw, which is that your select may pass, but you could _still_ end up with duplicates.  For an easy solution, just let MySQL handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try REPLACE in mysql:

```
REPLACE ...
```

Comment: add more description